# Check if string contains substring in array AND get the match

Tags: ruby

I've seen a couple threads here that shows the most efficient way to check a string against an array of substrings and return a boolean if there is a match.

```
str = "foobazbar"
arr = ["baz", "clowns"]
result = arr.any? { |substring| str.include?(substring) } # solution
result => true
```

However, as elegant and efficient as that solution is, is there any way to return the match itself? Using the example from above, I also want to know that the match was `baz`. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Umm, your code example doesn't match your result. `"foobazbar"` does not contain the substring `"baz, clowns"`, so `result` should be `false`.

Comment: If `"baz"` and `"clowns"` are the substrings you are looking for, you will first have to parse the contents of the array.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Woops, made a typo in the `arr` line. Fixed it. Seems like the solution posted by @Ursus works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = "foobazbar"
arr = ["baz", "clowns"]
result = arr.find { |s| str.include?(s) }
```

`result` at this point is the first element in `arr` that is a substring of `str` or is `nil`

Comment: Follow up question: What would be a good way to get an array of all matches rather than just the first element that matches?

`arr = ["foo","clowns", "baz"]`
`result => ["foo","baz"]`

Comment: @erli: Replace `find` by `select`.

Answer (score 5):

```
str = "foobazbar"
arr = ["baz", "clowns", "bar"]
```

```
r = Regexp.union(arr) #=> /baz|clowns|bar/
```

```
str[r]                #=> "baz"
str.scan(r)           #=> ["baz", "bar"]
```

See [Regexp::union](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union), [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-scan).